# Automatic running of functions in python?

Tags: python, function

"I'am making a list of functions in python but when i run the program the all functions in the list are get automatically called."

"I've tried it on python 3.7.3 and the same concept i also tried in C++ but there also it does the same."

```
    def a():
        print ('a')
    def b():
        print('b')
    def c():
        print('c')
    def d():
        print('d')
    aa=[a(),b(),c(),d()]
    print(aa[1])
```

"I expect the output of aa[1] to be 'b', but in output all the function get called and it gives output
a
b
c
d
None
"

Comment: your functions don't return anything.

Comment: change your `print(#)` to `return #`

Comment: You explicitly call all your functions here: `aa=[a(),b(),c(),d()]`.

Comment: Your functions *are* run, though not automatically; you explicitly call them in the expression that defines `aa`. The problem is that you are confusing standard output with the value of a function call.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
Also try working through a tutorial on function calls.  These should help clear up a couple of your problems, and reduce the confusion to one or two points you can handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `return` instead of `print`.  When you create your list `aa`, each element is being called immediately, because you've written `()` after each element - so consequently each print statement is being run as your list is built.  Additinally, when a function doesn't explicitly return a value, it returns `None`.  When you `print(aa[1])`, you're then printing the return value of b(), which is None.  So altogether you get:

```
a     # because it's printed in a()
b     # because it's printed in b()
c     # because it's printed in c()
d     # because it's printed in d()
None  # because it's returned from b()
```

If you use `return` instead of `print` in each function, each element of the list will then contain the value *returned* by each function (your list would effectively become `aa = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`).  Then, when you then `print(aa[1])`, you'd print the value of `aa` in position 1, which would be `'b'`.

```
def a():
    return 'a'
def b():
    return 'b'
def c(): 
    return 'c' 
def d():
    return 'd'
aa=[a(),b(),c(),d()] 
print(aa[1])
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to keep your print statements in each function, you could build your list with *references* to each function instead of calling each function - and then run the result:

```
def a():
    print ('a')
def b():
    print('b')
def c():
    print('c')
def d():
    print('d')
aa=[a,b,c,d]
print(aa[1]())
```

By putting `()` after the `aa[1]`, you're saying, *try to run whatever is returned from `aa[1]`*.  Since `aa[1]` contains a *reference* to function `b`, you're effectively calling `b()` at that point, which will then run your `print('b')` statement.

Answer (score 1):

your functions do not return anything. They only print a letter and return None.

use

```
def a():
    print ('a')
    return 'a'

...
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

You explicitly called all the functions when you wrote
[a(), b(), c(), d()]
so all of them running (in this case printing a letter) is the expected output indeed.
I believe what you want is to collect the callables in a list first **without calling them**. If you want then a desired function out of that list to run by indexing, you can do so by calling only afterward.

For example,

```
def a():
    print ('a')
def b():
    print('b')
def c():
    print('c')
def d():
    print('d')

# placeholder for the functions
funcs = [a, b, c, d]
```

Then you can call any of the functions by indexing:

```
# call any of them by indexing whenever you feel like it.
funcs[1]()

Output: b
```